# Capitalisation in python3 input

Tags: python, input

I would like to make a python file that ignores lower or uppercase for input, just the text

here is what i am working with

```
option = input("Admin, Member, Localhost> ")
if option =="admin" or option =="member" or option =="localhost":
    print("You chose {}".format(option))
else:
    exit()
```

I would like the user to be able to input the words like this **"admin AdMiN or ADMIN"**,
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The shortest version would be:

```
if option.lower() in ('admin', 'member', 'localhost'):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.lower()` function:

```
if option.lower() =="admin" or option.lower() =="member" or option.lower() =="localhost":
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20lower#str.lower):

> Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters 4 converted to lowercase.